# Select a column from a named list

Tags: r

I'm not sure I understand the type of variable I'm working with. It's the result of a binary classifier:

```
> mod_binary$predictions %>% glimpse()
 num [1:10000, 1:2] 0.989 0.904 0.99 0.989 0.989 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "FALSE" "TRUE"
> mod_binary$predictions %>% head()
         FALSE       TRUE
[1,] 0.9894592 0.01054078
[2,] 0.9044349 0.09556509
[3,] 0.9898756 0.01012441
[4,] 0.9888804 0.01111959
[5,] 0.9890123 0.01098766
[6,] 0.9641537 0.03584634
```

What is this variable type called? A list? A named list? A named vector?

I would like to retrieve a vector of the TRUE predictions. Tried:

```
> mod_binary$predictions$TRUE
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "mod_binary$predictions$TRUE"

> mod_binary$predictions[["TRUE"]]
Error in mod_binary$predictions[["TRUE"]] : subscript out of bounds

> mod_binary$predictions[[1]]
[1] 0.9894592
```

That last one returned a single observation, and actually the wrong one. It's the FALSE prediction (see the call to `head()` above)

How can I get just a vector of predicted probabilities for TRUE?

Comment: You can always check what you're dealing with - `class(mod_binary$predictions)` or `mod_binary$predictions %>% class` if you need to confirm.

Comment: Good to know, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a `matrix` from the attributes showed in the `glimpse` and also from the printed format of the data especially the row names (`[1,]`).  So, the `$` won't work for extraction.

According to `?Extract`

> The default methods work somewhat differently for atomic vectors, matrices/arrays and for recursive (list-like, see is.recursive) objects. $ is only valid for recursive objects, and is only discussed in the section below on recursive objects.

```
mod_binary$predictions[, "TRUE"]
```

Comment: Thank you, this does what I need. How did you know it was a matrix? Is it possible to tell from glimpse() or str()?

Comment: @DougFir  I saw it on the `glimpse` `attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2`